# Diary view- user interface

Tags: website-design

I need to design a user inteface which shows the user his/her list of appointments.
Ideally it needs to show today, tomorrow, this week, this month as view options

for filtering, user can choose open/closed/all appointments.

I am looking for a diary view interface in existing websites for this. any reference urls for the same ?

Answer (score 1):

All the big calendar sites have an agenda view of some sort:

- Google Calendar
- Yahoo Calendar
- 30boxes.com